# В чем ошибка?!

Tags: php

Начал изучать пхп. Прохожу тему функции. Написал функцию на вывод ссылки.

```
<?php

function link()
{
    echo "<a href='http://vkontakte.ru'>Сайт Вконтакте</a>";
} // line 15

link();

?>
```

Запускаю, браузер выдает такую ошибку:

> `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare link() in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\function2.php on line 15`

А line 15 - это закрывающая фигурная дужка функции. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, функция с таким именем уже существует, ты пытаешься ее пересоздать, этого нельзя сделать, назови ее иначе.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP уже есть [функция с именем link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.link.php), переименуйте свою функцию, и все заработает.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Но дело в том, что писал с видеоурока, запись идентична - там пошло, а у меня нет. Извините, может туплю где, но логики не вижу.

Comment: Видеоуроки - зло имхо) Скорее всего у автора php 3 либо сборка без этих функций (link, symlink etc.)

Comment: а что за видеуроки?

Comment: Знаете, я тоже такого мнения) сам всегда так говорил) но я только начал изучать. Мне пока нужны основы и понимания работы языка. И я нашел неплохие уроки Евгения Попова. Понятное дело, что изучать язык серьезно по видео - это бред, но как для начала - сгодиться. Может, посоветуете, что нужно новичку для изучения пхп (не видео))). Буду рад.

Comment: А вот отметьте на главной теги php + обучение и будет вам счастье) Много подобных вопросов было.

Comment: Видео Евгения Попова. Для начинающих пойдет. А человеку, который уже кое-что знает - ничего полезного. Уроки как раз для того, чтобы описать на простых примерах, как работает язык, что он собой представляет, ну и общие положения.